# Displaying unicode characters using python

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a string that prints out like this

```
print a
\u4f53\u91cd\u8a08
```

I am using eclipse and the console can print unicode characters, I have tested it like this.

```
print u'\u4f53\u91cd\u8a08'
体重計
```

It prints out correctly, how can I make the string in the variable a to be printed like above.

Thanks very much for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode using the `unicode-escape` codec.

```
>>> print '\\u4f53\\u91cd\\u8a08'.decode('unicode-escape')
体重計
```

Or if what you have is actually a JSON fragment, decode as JSON.

```
>>> print json.loads('"\\u4f53\\u91cd\\u8a08"')
体重計
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps...

```
print unicode(a)
```

would do the trick?

If the string itself actually has escaped escapes in it (i.e. if you were to write it, it'd be something more like `u'\\u4f53\\u91cd\\u8a08'`), then use:

```
print a.decode('unicode-escape')
```