# Convert hex string to a char in Python

Tags: python, hex

Python shows a literal string value, and uses escape codes in the console:

```
>>> x = '\x74\x65\x73\x74'
>>> x
'test'
>>> print(x)
test
```

How can I do the same when reading from a file?

```
$ cat test.txt 
\x74\x65\x73\x74

$ cat test.py 
with open('test.txt') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
        print(line)

$ python3 test.py
\x74\x65\x73\x74
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying unicode characters using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487499/displaying-unicode-characters-using-python)

Comment: How did such a file come about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to preserve the hex representation into a bytes-like sequence of escaped hex characters. Then use [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to convert from a bytes-like object to a regular str. You can use the [`unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings) Python-specific encoding as the encoding type.

```sh
$ cat test.txt
\x74\x65\x73\x74

$ cat test.py
with open('test.txt', "rb") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        print(line)
        print(line.decode("unicode_escape"))

$ python3 test.py
b'\\x74\\x65\\x73\\x74\n'
test
```

Answer (score 1):

using string encode and decode function

refer [this](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) for python standard encodings

for python 2

```
line = "\\x74\\x65\\x73\\x74"
line = line.decode('string_escape')
# test
```

for python3

```
line = "\\x74\\x65\\x73\\x74"
line = line.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
# test
```